# Android Create ListView on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-widget

I am trying to create search activity. The layout contains `EditText` (to type search query) `Button` & `ListView` (to show search results). search_layout.xml (For showing searchbox & `ListView`) is as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_search"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search_practice" />

         <Button 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/button_search"
             android:onClick="searchPractice" />

    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/praclist"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And layout for list items list_items.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">  
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
        <!-- Description label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip">
        </TextView>
        <!-- Linear layout for cost and price Cost: Rs.100 -->
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Cost Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Phone: " >
        </TextView>
        <!-- Price Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac" 
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="left">
        </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

On button click (searchBtnClick) I am calling method doMySearch :

```
public void searchBtnClick(View view){
  -------
  ------
  ListAdapter adapter = doSearch(query);
  ListView pracListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.praclist);
  PracListView.setAdapter(adapter);
  return;
}

private ListAdapter doSearch(String query){
    ListAdapter adapter = null;
String url = "https://mywebservice.com/apps/api/v1/search/practices?val="+query+"&by=nam";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
String jsonResponsse = null;


try{
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    jsonResponsse = getASCIIContentFromEntity(httpEntity);          
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    PracticesByName practicesByName = gson.fromJson(jsonResponsse,PracticesByName.class);
    ArrayList<Practices> practiceList = (ArrayList<Practices>)practicesByName.getPractices();
    for(int i=0 ; i < practiceList.size() ; i ++){   
        Object a = practiceList.get(i);
        System.out.println(a.getClass() + "   " + a.toString());
        Practices aPractice = practiceList.get(i);
        HashMap<String, String> aMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        aMap.put(TAG_NAME, aPractice.getName());
        aMap.put(TAG_CITY, aPractice.getCity());
        aMap.put(TAG_EMAIL, aPractice.getEmail());
        aMap.put(TAG_PHONE, aPractice.getPhone());


        searchResultList.add(aMap);


    }


    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, searchResultList,
            R.layout.list_item_prac_search,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_CITY, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE}, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.city, R.id.email, R.id.phone});
    //pracListView.setAdapter(adapter);


}catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception while getting serach for practice");
        e.printStackTrace();
}

return adapter;

}
```

The code is running fine. I am getting search result from web service. But don't see any list below. Any idea what I am messing up?

Comment: Anyone there who can answer the Android questions ?

Comment: What are the elements in the listadapter?  Show some of the code in `doSearch`

Comment: Please see below links for Searchbar in ListView [Android Search in ListView Example](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html) [Android Sectioned Listview with Search Bar](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html)

Comment: @AleksG - added code of doSearch()

Comment: These are the examples in which 1st preparing the list view & then searching through that ListView. I am searching (calling the web service to get search data) & then displaying search results in ListView.

Comment: I know it's not the suggestion you expect, but try writing your own adapter - it's easy.  Then go through the `getView` method with a debugger to see if you are actually populating the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Got it working. Corrected **search_layout.xml** as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_search"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search_practice"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

         <Button 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:text="@string/button_search"
             android:onClick="searchPractice" />         
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/praclist"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

making outer layout vertical & placing horizontal layout (containing EditText & Search Button in it) and ListView in it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create an array lis to fetch the recorde from the query,

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add(doSearch(query));
```

Then replace this line,

```
ListAdapter adapter = doSearch(query);
```

with this line,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,items);
ListView pracListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.praclist);
  PracListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: The code of preparing list & adapter is there in doSearch method. I am  just returning adapter from doSearch

Comment: why have you used _layout xml_ . This type of xmls are used in case of customized lists, not for default lists.

Comment: Then how we can display more than one items (In my case $ items : Name, city , email phone) in ListView ?

Comment: I guess the problem is with  search_layout.xml . I am messing up there something. If you can figure out what it that then it would bea great help..Thanx..

Comment: you have already messed up. Now tell what you want in your list. do you want each separate record in a single row. Like my name, city, phone, email in one row, your name and other details in second row.??

Comment: Yes.  Exactly that is what I want in ListView

Comment: for this you have to create a customized adpater.

Comment: No. We can do with SimpleAdapter. I have found one tutorial & tested. Its is [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). And it is working.

Comment: its good, if it is working. Though i have solved quite same issue with my own customized list.